# Случайное число от 1 до 100

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Почему в данном коде к результату прибавляется единица?

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Этот код выведет число от 1 до 100 включительно, или от 2 до 99?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Метод `Math.random()` возвращает псевдослучайное число с плавающей запятой из диапазона [0, 1), то есть, от 0 (включительно) до 1 (но не включая 1), которое затем можно отмасштабировать до нужного диапазона.

Следовательно при умножении на `100` мы получаем диапазон `от 0 до 99`, и при инкременте этого диапазона на `1` получим `от 1 до 100`.

Если вы хотите получить диапазон `от 2 до 99`, то вам нужны следующие коэффициенты:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 98) + 2
```

Если вы хотите получить диапазон `от 0 до 100`, то вам нужен следующий коэффициент:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
```

---

Тут есть еще один важный момент- какой метод вы используете для округления: 
`Math.floor`, `Math.round` или `Math.ceil`.

В случае с `Math.floor`- округление вниз. Округляет аргумент до ближайшего меньшего целого.

```
Math.floor(1.9) = 1
```

В случае с `Math.round` возвращает ближайшее целое число.

```
Math.round(1.5) = 2
Math.round(1.4) = 1
```

В случае с `Math.ceil` - округление вверх. Округляет аргумент до ближайшего большего целого.

```
Math.ceil(1.1) = 2
```

Следовательно:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*100) - диапазон от 0 до 99
Math.round(Math.random()*100) - диапазон от 0 до 100
Math.ceil(Math.random()*100) - диапазон от 1 до 100
```

Резюмируя: лучше использовать `Math.floor` или `Math.ceil` как методы округления, т.к. в случае с `Math.round` мы получаем неравномерную вероятность выпадения для нижней и верхней границы по `0.4(9)` против `0.(9)` для всех остальных целых чисел диапазона.

Пример: от `0` до `0.4(9)` округляется до `0`, от `99.5` до `99.(9)` округляется до `100` против скажем от `2.5` до `3.4(9)`, которое округлится до `2`.

Ссылки: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624834/6677992), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp).

Comment: Спасибо, за исчерпывающий ответ. Нет, мне нужно как раз от 0 до 100.
Не понимал просто что за единица, теперь понял. А почему бы вместо floor не использовать round? Это приведет к другому результату?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев тогда вам нужно домножить на 101.

Comment: @Anamnian 101 - ??

Comment: @Igor верно, [Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) Return a random number between 1 and 100: Т.е. без инкремента возвращает 0-99, чтобы получить 0-100 надо домножить на 101

Comment: Я запутался. Есть разница между Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; и Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) ?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев В первом случае диапазон от 1 до 100, во втором от 0 до 100. Разница в начальной границе.

Comment: Все, спасибо, понял. А есть разница в использовании Math.floor , и Math.round ? Разве второй метод не был бы очевиднее?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев У них разные назначения- `floor` возвращает наибольшее целое число, меньше или равное, а `round` возвращает ближайшее целое. то есть на `1.6` `floor` вернет `1`, а `round` вернет `2`.

Comment: @Anamnian мне показалось, что Вы отвечали на вопрос про `round`

Comment: @Anamnian Да. Значит ли это можно использовать оба варианта? Или в случае с round будет выход за диапазон от 1 до 100?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев Т.е. если использовать `Math.round` как метод округления- то получим от 0 до 100 при данном коде: `Math.round(Math.random() * 100)`

Comment: @Anamnian Да, я так и предполагал. Спасибо! Сегодня я узнал много нового.

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев Резюмируя: лучше использовать `Math.floor` или `Math.ceil` как методы округления, т.к. в случае с `Math.round` мы получаем неравномерную вероятность выпадения для нижней и верхней границы по `0.5` и `0.4(9)` против `0.(9)` для всех остальных целых чисел диапазона. То есть от `0` до `0.5` округляется до `0`, от `99.5` до `99.(9)` округляется до `100` против скажем от `2.5` до `3.4(9)`, которое округлится до `2`.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> ... returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
>   number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)
>
> ... возвращает псевдо-случайное число с плавающей точкой в диапазоне 0-1
>   (включая ноль, но не включая один)

Comment: Спасибо! А что значит псевдо-случайное?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).